# December 2012 Migration Not Available in App Dashboard

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently took over development of a mobile website that uses the Facebook Graph API with Javascript. After the Wednesday Sept 6th update the app stopped letting people re-authorize to Facebook. Initial authorization works, but requesting another auth throws some generic "user denied your request" exception. Which, then redirects to an error page on FB that doesn't even exist.

I think the issue could be related to the oAuth changes that are in staging for the *Announcing December 2012 Breaking Changes (90-Day Notice)*. I would like to DISABLE this migration, but I don't see it in my Facebook App Dashboard.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If Facebook API changed so that it broke your application, you must follow Facebook recommendations and update your application. It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to enable/disable December 2012 Breaking Changes in the app settings will be available in a few days after it has been announced.

Thus, the breaking changes aren't in effect yet, which means your error is not related to the December 2012 Breaking Changes.